# Select2 after fixing the parentModal issue the modal was disabled after requesting the data using ajax. How do i to make the Modal active?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, bootstrap-4, jquery-select2

Am using select2 jquery plugin for searching the options, after selecting the particular option ma using the onchange event listener for javascript to trigger the function for searching the data to the backed then i return the html component view response with particular data.

The problem was this all components i put them on top of modal. Firstly the search box for select2 was disables but later on i figured out how to activate it by including 'parentModal' Option at the moment the select2 is initialized.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#serviceProviderItem").select2({
            dropdownParent: $("#viewSMAIViewServiceProviderItemsModal")
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem came after selection the option and when the ajax request is sent. The Modal is disabled. Any one with idea how to make that right.

[Modal disabled. I can't scroll down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shI4V.png)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer how to make it work.

I activated the modal after getting the response from the ajax request using the below code.

```
<script>
    function view_service_provider_item_details_with_options_and_variates_(serviceProvideItemID) {

        $("#loaderViewServiceProviderItemDetails").show();
        $.post("{{url('view_specific_service_provider_item_details')}}",{serviceProviderItemID:serviceProvideItemID,
            serviceProviderID:'{{$serviceProviderID}}',_token:"{{csrf_token()}}"}).done(function (e) {
            $('#viewServiceProviderItemDetails').html(e);
            $('#loaderViewServiceProviderItemDetails').hide();
        });
        $("#viewSMAIViewServiceProviderItemsModal}").showPopup();
    }
</script>
```